# "Contra felicem vix deus vires habet" - Need advice on replacing the word "Felicem"

Tags: syntax, word-request, motto

For context, this is for a tattoo I'd like to get but I want to make sure it's syntactically correct as best as possible.

I think the phrase is a great one, however I would very much prefer it to be something along the lines of "determined", "fierce", "resolved" (etc.) instead of "lucky".

So I pose a few questions here - 
Would it be syntactically correct to simply replace felicem with, for example, Certus?

- Any recommended words? My Latin knowledge is near enough no better than your average Joe.
- If this is too complex or can't be done with a high degree of certainty, any alternative phrases with a similar connotation?

(Also. Though I like the phrase, I can't seem to find it's origin. Anyone know?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You asked about its origin. It is in the Sententiae of Publilius Syrus. Here, towards the end of the section devoted to the letter "C".

https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/Chronologia/Lsante01/Publilius/pub_sent.html#c

It is a verse in iambic trimeter, so if you want to replace "felicem" by another word it might be an idea to find one with the same metrical footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Adjective, "felix" is in the accusative case "felicem" (masculine/ feminine) = happy; lucky; fruitful; fortunate; successful. Here, of course, it means "lucky (man)", where "man" is understood. (The Romans used fewer words, than we do, to convey the same meanings.) Therefore, you may substitute any adjective, in the accusative case.

How about "audax" = bold; courageous; audacious; resolute; desperate (Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict.)?

In the requisite accusative case this fellow is: "audacem".

Alternatively, "fortis" = strong, powerful; hardy; courageous; valiant; manful.

Accusative is "fortem".

Good luck with the tattoo!

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far guys. (I couldn't find a reply button, sorry!). Are there any other words similar to audacem that would allude to valiance, strength or determination that would work? Apologies if that's a naïve question as far as this goes. I really know nothing, not unlike Jon Snow. :(

Comment: That would leave two adjacent vowels; elision? *Contr' audacem...*

Comment: @Hugh: Does elision disqualify "audacem"?

Comment: It could, but if I remember right it's absolutely not unheard of for a poet to use hiatus to make the meter work out right.

Comment: @Faz From the word "commasculo" meaning "to screw up one's courage/to make (one) manly," you could use the past participle "having been made manly/having been invigorated." I lack the knowledge to check if this is idiomatic, so another commenter might be moved to do that.

Comment: @Draconis: An elided vowel would be put in brackets, so barely pronounced. This does not help a tattoo aficionado (suggested alternative, "fortem"). Allen & Greenough: elision can be omitted if a word, ending in a vowel, has a special emphasis (p612-15; original: p411; reprint). Would "audacem" have a special emphasis? Is it one of those "in the eye of the beholder" things?